# I forgot if I have taken "X" vaccine. Can the re-vaccination cause problems?

Tags: vaccination

I don't remember and lost the documentation of wich vaccines I have taken in the past, for some of them (luckily, I know many I've taken). I would like to know if vaccinating again could pose health problems.

If this is the 1st time I will vaccinate myself, then probably my age now is not appropriate for a certain vaccine I should have taken when I was a baby.

I think that if this is the second time I take a vaccine, then that would not be a problem, since my antibodies are already prepared for the antigens. They may recognize the antigens on the vaccine substance and they will probably attack them, but since they are just antigen carriers, not pathogens like virus or bacteria, they will not produce me any disease. I will have immunological system reactions but that will pass quickly.

Comment: I think you pretty much answered your own question. Except for the possible symptoms produced by an immune response (this is what makes some people think a flu vaccine gives them the flu, for example), a second vaccine won't cause any sort of illness.